# iCloud Bookmarks and page monitoring add-on/extension in one browser on OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: browser, safari, icloud, bookmarks, add-on

I'd like to use only one browser (preferably safari, chrome oder firefox) where I have my bookmarks from the iCloud on my MacBook running Yosemite. Furthermore, I'd also like to have a page monitoring add on/extension for this certain browser. The methods I found so far are:

1. Two browsers: Safari for bookmarks and Chrome with Page Monitor add-on.
2. Chrome with page monitor and [this add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icloud-bookmarks/fkepacicchenbjecpbpbclokcabebhah) (works only on windows).
3. Using Safari and installing an extra app ([Changes Meter](http://intuiware.com/apps/changes-meter)) for monitoring. I tried this app, but it looks like it has troubles with the webpages I'm monitoring as it says after every check, that there were changes, although there weren't.
4. Using Chrome with Page Monitor and sync bookmarks between Chrome and Safari with [Xmarks Sync](https://www.xmarks.com). But this gives troubles, as iCloud and Xmarks don't really work out together, means the bookmarks I add in Chrome are synced with Xmarks to Safari, but then won't added to cloud bookmarks...

As these methods are not satisfying for me I'd like to ask if you have a solution for this (using one browser with both features)?